# Sous vide "Jabon de Paris" (Cooked ham)

Tags: food-preservation, pork, ham

I would like to use sous vide to prepare "Jambon de Paris" from a raw piece of pork.

I have been doing tests on my own, and 8 hours at 65°C with 4% salt, 1% sugar, and a good amount of white and black pepper yields a satisfactory result in terms of taste and texture.

The issue now is how to make sure that it is shelf-stable as the store-bought one. [This](https://fabriquedelices.com/wmm_product/jambon-de-paris-paris-style-cooked-ham/), for instance, has a shelf life of 26 weeks.

I have been trying to find recipes on the Internet with no success, as most of the recipes for cooked ham are, basically, glazing an already cooked ham.

Comment: Note that the store bought one has a shelf life of 7 days in the refrigerator once the package is open. Achieving their result likely has as much to do with how to package it as how it's prepared.

Comment: When you say "shelf stable", do you actually mean at ambient temperature, or in the fridge? The linked item isn't clear on that point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you are going to make this shelf-stable, which, in part, comes from the dramatic reduction of water activity in a product. Cooked hams are generally products that must remain refrigerated.  They can last quite a while in the refrigerator, especially in the original packaging.  For your purposes, the process is clearly explained in Douglas Baldwin's excellent [guide to sous vide cooking](https://www.douglasbaldwin.com/sous-vide.html).  In particular, you want to pay attention to the Food Safety section found in part 1, and especially the part titled "pathogens of interest."  Here, he specifies how long products can be held when cooked to pasteurization temperatures in a sealed pouch, rapidly chilled, then held at refrigeration or freezer temperatures.  However, once the seal is broken and you begin to use the product, you begin a different, much shorter "clock."  That is why the ham in your example must be eaten within 7 days, once the package is opened.

Comment: I'm not sure the OP is using "shelf stable" in quite the sense you or I might. I've seen similar ham products with long *fridge* lives, but the only hams that can be kept at room temperature are cured/dried (or tinned).

Comment: @ChrisH fair point, but "shelf-stable" has a meaning, particularly in our context.

Comment: Indeed. I've also queried the OP, as I think they may be using the term incorrectly. I looked at the linked product and it says "shelf life" in a table (I wouldn't use that term for fridge life but some would); it also refers to "pate" in the storage instructions so their proofreading isn't great at all

Comment: @ChrisH The website reads a bit like it was Google translated from French with some minimal proofreading by a non-English speaker.